# Flashing Zenfone 6 (A6001g): stuck at E: unknown volume "/spare"

Tags: adb, rom-flashing

I need help with my zenfone 6 (a6001g).

Issue Origin:
I was trying to flash my zf6 (trying to downgrade from to ww-2.22.44 so I could upgrade to 3.23 (lollipop). I used Asus Flash tool latest version and .raw file for zf6.

Problem:
I mistakenly selected "Wipe Data", but then when I tried to flash, im stuck at

ERASE spare...
E:unknown volume "/spare"

I was trying to use adb directly but then it cant detect my phone.
"List of devices attached" is showing blank.

Need your help please...